# #1413 error in mysql while creating a trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

using mysql in phpmyadmin i started creating a trigger..
but i got this error

```
MySQL said: #1413 - Duplicate handler declared in the same block
```

I dont know whch is going wrong.. also i am creating trigger with three loops for the first time.. I am a beginner too.. Help me to solve this..
It may be a repeated question. I need to understand what is wrong with my trigger.
this trigger will execute after inserting to the table `external`

My trigger contains

```
BEGIN
DECLARE scode varchar(30);
DECLARE grade varchar(30);
DECLARE val integer;
DECLARE credit integer;
DECLARE gval integer;
DECLARE temp double;
DECLARE cgpa decimal(4,3);
DECLARE t double;
DECLARE done int default false;
DECLARE done1 int default false;
DECLARE done2 int default false;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT Sub_Code,Grade FROM external where Reg_No=new.Reg_No;
DECLARE continue handler for not found set done=true;
DECLARE continue handler for not found set done1=true;
DECLARE continue handler for not found set done2=true;
SET credit=0;
OPEN cur1;
my_loop: loop
set done=false;
fetch cur1 into scode,grade;
if done then
leave my_loop;
end if;
DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT Credits FROM subj_mast WHERE Sub_Code=scode;
OPEN cur2;
my_loop1: loop
set done1=false;
fetch cur2 into val;
if done1 then
leave my_loop1;
end if;
set credit=credit+val;
DECLARE cur3 CURSOR FOR SELECT gvalue FROM gradevalue where Grade=grade;
OPEN cur3;
my_loop2: loop
set done2=false;
fetch cur3 into gval;
if done2 then
leave my_loop2;
end if;
set temp=val*gval;
set t=t+temp;
end loop my_loop;
end loop my_loop1;
end loop my_loop2;
set cgpa=t/credit;
close cur1;
close cur2;
close cur3;
insert into result values(new.Reg_No,cgpa);
END
```

this may be a too much code . but i need a clear answer.. Waiting for answers..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error message is very clear that *Duplicate handler declared in the same block*.

When you have multiple cursors, you can make use of a single `not found` handler with proper care.

**Option 1 Possibility**:

1. Looping through Cursor 1 should not call opening of either of Cursor 2 and Cursor 3.
2. Then, on closing Cursor 1, reset the same `done` variable and use with next cursor.
3. Open next cursor and follow above two steps.
4. With this option possibility, you don't need to *declare* multiple
   *same type* handlers *in the same block*.

**Option 2 Possibility**:

In your code you are declaring other cursors while looping through previous cursors fetch results. That part is another error. You can't *`DECLARE`* wherever you want. All *`DECLARE`* statements must be on top of a *`BEGIN`* block. Hence, if you want to define another cursor based on *fetch result* of another cursor, use another *`BEGIN --- END`* block.

Change your trigger body as follows:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE scode varchar(30);
    DECLARE grade varchar(30);
    DECLARE val integer;
    DECLARE credit integer;
    DECLARE gval integer;
    DECLARE temp double;
    DECLARE cgpa decimal(4,3);
    DECLARE t double;

    DECLARE done int default false;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
                 SELECT Sub_Code, Grade FROM external where Reg_No = new.Reg_No;
    DECLARE continue handler for not found set done = true;

    SET credit = 0;

    OPEN cur1;

    my_loop: loop
        fetch cur1 into scode, grade;
        if done then
            leave my_loop;
        end if;
        BEGIN
            DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR 
                         SELECT Credits FROM subj_mast WHERE Sub_Code = scode;
            DECLARE continue handler for not found set done1 = true;

            OPEN cur2;

            my_loop1: loop
                fetch cur2 into val;
                if done1 then
                    leave my_loop1;
                end if;

                set credit = credit + val;

                BEGIN
                    DECLARE cur3 CURSOR FOR 
                                 SELECT gvalue FROM gradevalue where Grade = grade;
                    DECLARE done2 int default false;

                    OPEN cur3;

                    my_loop2: loop
                        fetch cur3 into gval;
                        if done2 then
                            leave my_loop2;
                        end if;

                        set temp = val * gval;
                        set t = t + temp;
                    end loop my_loop2;

                    close cur3;
                END;
            end loop my_loop1;

            close cur2;
        END;
    end loop my_loop;

    close cur1;

    set cgpa = t / credit;

    insert into result values( new.Reg_No, cgpa );
END;
```

**Document Reference**:

[***DECLARE Syntax***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html)

> *`DECLARE`* is permitted only inside a *`BEGIN ... END`* compound statement
>   and must be at its start, before any other statements.
>
> Declarations must follow a certain order. Cursor declarations must
>   appear before handler declarations. Variable and condition
>   declarations must appear before cursor or handler declarations

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you sir... need a clarification.. Is it possible to declare a cursor after closing all other cursors in a trigger?for eg like  `END;
    end loop my_loop1;
    close cur1;
    DECLARE done4 int default false;
    DECLARE cur4 CURSOR FOR SELECT Sub_Code FROM history_of_arrear where Reg_No = new.Reg_No;
    DECLARE continue handler for not found set done4 = true;
    OPEN cur4;` but i am getting 1064 syntax error near `declare done4` please clarify this...